# Error Code 1603. Java Update did not complete. Java error

Tags: java

Error Code 1603. Java Update did not complete. I have a java error

I think it is a server problem, the first time I create my server and the user interface does not open.

Comment: https://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml and https://www.thewindowsclub.com/error-code-1603-java-update-did-not-complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml

> ### Option 1: Restart your system and uninstall old versions
>
> **Restart your system before installing**
>
> 1. Once you see the 1603 error, restart your system.
> 2. Download and install the [offline installer](https://java.com/winoffline_installer/) package.
> 3. When prompted, choose Save in the download dialog box, and save the download package in a convenient place (e.g. save on the desktop).
> 4. Double click on the downloaded installation file to start the installation process.
>
> **Uninstall Java versions before installing**
>
> 1. If the above instructions fail to resolve the issue, it is recommended that you [uninstall all existing Java versions](https://java.com/en/download/help/uninstall_java.xml) from
>      the system.
> 2. Reboot the system after you uninstall all Java versions, before trying to install.
>
> ### Option 2: Disable Java content through the Java Control Panel
>
> This option disables Java content in the browser prior to installing.
>
> 1. Once you see the 1603 error, close the installer.
> 2. [Find and launch the Java Control Panel](https://java.com/en/download/help/win_controlpanel.xml)
> 3. Uncheck (de-select) **Enable Java content in the browser** option
>
>    - In the Java Control Panel, click the **Security tab**.
>    - Uncheck the option **Enable Java content in the browser**.
>    - Click **Apply** and then **OK** to confirm the changes.
> 4. Reinstall Java and re-enable Java content in the browser
>
>    - Download and install the [offline installer](https://java.com/winoffline_installer/) package.
>    - After the installation has completed, re-enable the option to **Enable Java content in the browser**, if you require running Java content in the browser.